# Can an ssh key be configured to reject a connection if it is not connecting to the right port?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, port

As sshd service can listen on different ports is it possible to configure a key which will work only if the connection was made on one port, but not the other?

By this I mean that the key appears more than once in the `authorized_keys` list and the connection will be permitted if it is made on the port specified in the key.

The idea is to use the same key but with a different `command=` and other option to allow the same key to be used for different services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you can:

```
Port 2222
Port 3333
Match LocalPort 2222
        AuthorizedKeysFile /path/to/authorized_keys_1
Match LocalPort 3333
        AuthorizedKeysFile /path/to/authorized_keys_2
```

See the [`Match`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) section of the `sshd_config(5)` manpage for more info about which criteria and directives you can use with a `Match` block.

Comment: Can the AuthorizedKeysFile contain more than key, like when multiple users are connecting to a service that port is dedicated to?
Can it also be extended to a source ip address or range?

Comment: Yes and yes. You can use multiple conditions in the `Match` directive: eg. `Match LocalPort 2222 Address 172.31.17.252/30` to only apply to clients which connect to the port 2222 from the `172.31.17.252-172.31.17.255` address range. Notice that you can experiment with sshd by running it as a regular user (as long as you don't bind to ports < 1024 and don't try to auth other users, you can do almost everything).

Comment: Whether this setup provides any additional security benefits is another question...